# STM32WB55 Thread Undefined Reference To Errors

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32cubemx

I'm trying to debug new thread ftd project. You can find my settings below:

```
> HSEM
> IPCC
> RCC -> HSE/LSE
> SYS -> Serial wire
> RTC
> LPUART1 & LPUART1 DMA
> USART1 & USART1 DMA
> RF
> STM32_WPAN as a THREAD
```

When I debug it, It gives me a lines of errors. You can find my errors below:

https://codeshare.io/9Oe7O0

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "Thread_FTD.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"C:\Users\a.e\Desktop\STM32Workspace\Thread_FTD\STM32WB55RGVX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="Thread_FTD.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./Core/Src/app_entry.o: in function `MX_APPE_Init':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:198: undefined reference to `AMM_Init'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:206: undefined reference to `LST_init_head'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:226: undefined reference to `AMM_BackgroundProcess'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./Core/Src/app_entry.o: in function `Config_HSE':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:380: undefined reference to `OTP_Read'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./Core/Src/app_entry.o: in function `appe_Tl_Init':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:449: undefined reference to `TL_Init'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:455: undefined reference to `shci_init'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:462: undefined reference to `TL_MM_Init'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:464: undefined reference to `TL_Enable'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:467: undefined reference to `shci_user_evt_proc'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./Core/Src/app_entry.o: in function `APPE_SysEvtReadyProcessing':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:529: undefined reference to `TL_TRACES_Init'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./Core/Src/app_entry.o: in function `ProcessTrace':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:704: undefined reference to `LST_remove_tail'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:709: undefined reference to `DbgTraceWrite'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:711: undefined reference to `AMM_Free'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../Core/Src/app_entry.c:701: undefined reference to `LST_is_empty'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.o: in function `APP_THREAD_Init':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:156: undefined reference to `SHCI_C2_THREAD_Init'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.o: in function `APP_THREAD_DeviceConfig':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:242: undefined reference to `otInstanceErasePersistentInfo'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:247: undefined reference to `otInstanceFinalize'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:248: undefined reference to `otInstanceInitSingle'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:249: undefined reference to `otSetStateChangedCallback'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:254: undefined reference to `otLinkSetChannel'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:259: undefined reference to `otLinkSetPanId'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:264: undefined reference to `otThreadSetNetworkKey'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:269: undefined reference to `otIp6SetEnabled'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:274: undefined reference to `otThreadSetEnabled'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.o: in function `APP_THREAD_StateNotif':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:303: undefined reference to `otThreadGetDeviceRole'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.o: in function `APP_THREAD_CheckWirelessFirmwareInfo':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:365: undefined reference to `SHCI_GetWirelessFwInfo'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.o: in function `Send_CLI_To_M0':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:629: undefined reference to `TL_CLI_SendCmd'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.o: in function `APP_THREAD_TL_THREAD_INIT':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:677: undefined reference to `TL_THREAD_Init'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.o: in function `APP_THREAD_ProcessMsgM0ToM4':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/App/app_thread.c:734: undefined reference to `OpenThread_CallBack_Processing'
C:/ST/STM32CubeIDE_1.13.2/STM32CubeIDE/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.11.3.rel1.win32_1.1.1.202309131626/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: ./STM32_WPAN/Target/hw_ipcc.o: in function `HW_IPCC_THREAD_CliNotEvtHandler':
C:/Users/a.e/Desktop/STM32Workspace/Thread_FTD/Debug/../STM32_WPAN/Target/hw_ipcc.c:422: undefined reference to `HW_IPCC_THREAD_CliEvtNot'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:68: Thread_FTD.elf] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

13:17:01 Build Failed. 44 errors, 1 warnings. (took 3s.218ms)
```

I tried enable all visibility at Project Manager -> Advanced Settings -> Generated Function Calls but it didn't work so I disabled LPUART1 and USART1 again. My clock configuration is corrent and I check every other configurations by looking the examples in STM32_WPAN Applications. I also check Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes and  Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Locations. All includes are applied so there is no error. How can I fix my problem?

Best regards.

Note: I also asked this question at ST form. There are some replies but non of them worked. You can find the question [link here](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-embedded-software/stm32wb55-thread-undefined-reference-to-errors/m-p/623175).

I tried to check path or source location error, include libraries by myself and update STM32CubeIDE and STM32CubeMX but non of them worked. I expecting zero error when I debug it.

Comment: You have 44 linker errors for undefined symbols.  To resolve them you have to link the object code or libraries in which they are defined.  Looks like multiple separate libraries.  Those prefixed `ot` refer to open thread. Others relate to STM32CubeWBA.  Probably a few others, I am not going to look them all up for you.  You need to add these components to your project.

Comment: Your .c files contain undefined function calls or refer to non-existing objects, probably  because you forgot to include some headers in them. Look at the very first linker error message: `/Core/Src/app_entry.c:198: undefined reference to 'AMM_Init'`. AMM_Init doesn't exist in that translation unit.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I solve the problem. I added "/FTD_Thread/Middlewares" in my source locations and it works.